# eclipse-rcp 2023-06 (4.28) + slf4j + logback = ClassCastException due to migration of eclipse to slf4j v2

Tags: eclipse-rcp, logback, slf4j

After migrating [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox), an eclipse-rcp based application, to eclipse 2023-06, the application fails to start with a CCE for logback :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext (org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @273842a6; ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5445f5ba)
    at org.titou10.jtb.util.SLF4JConfigurator.configure(SLF4JConfigurator.java:47)
```

The app uses plugins slf4j.api v2.0.7, ch.qos.logbaqck.core v1.2.12 and ch.qos.logbaqck.classic v1.2.12

The eclipse 2023-06 release notes indicates that eclipe now uses slf4j.api version 2 and some actions must be taken for rcp apps to run with v2023-06 ([Logging API SLF4J version 2](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.28/platform.php#slf4j.api-version-2)):

> {...} Eclipse Platform ships org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle by default. If you assemble a final application you have to ensure that this bundle is automatically activated during startup. For an Eclipse Product this can be achieved by assigning the Plug-in org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle a suitable start-level in the Configuration section of your product

But my freshly installed eclipse-rcp 2023-06 does not include plugin `org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle` and it is also not in the latest orbit repository

The slf4j/logback subsystem is configured by some code inspired by the vogella tutorial on logging [Configuring Logback](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html#configuring-logback):

```
JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(); -> CCE occurs here
configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
loggerContext.reset();
try (InputStream configurationStream = new URL(LOGBACK_XML).openStream()) {
   configurator.doConfigure(configurationStream);
} {...}
```

I've looked at [Migrate to SLF4J-2 from Maven-Central](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/issues/588) that gives details on the migration to slf4j v2.0 but I didn't find anything to make my app to start

I must says that it was working well with eclipse 2023-03

Q:

- what may be wrong?
- where can I find the`org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle`plugin?
- is there somewhere a working example of an rcp app with eclipse 2023-06 that configure slf4j by itself like describe by vogella's tutorials? Is it still the right way to do it

Links to some code in JMSToolBox:

- [SLF4JConfigurator](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.core/src/org/titou10/jtb/util/SLF4JConfigurator.java)
- [JMSToolBox "product" with configuration and plugins](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.product/org.titou10.jtb.product)

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the comment here https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/issues/588#issuecomment-1410438615 from Mr Vogella Himself, I managed to move the code to use slf4j v2+logback v1.3 by creating a target that includes `org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle`and`logback v1.3`

Q:

- is this the way to go starting from eclipse 2023-06 for apps that uses slf4j+logback? ie we need to create a specific eclipse target?

If so, I'll answer myself here and document for reference what I did to move my app from eclipse 2023-03 + slf4j v1.7 + logback v1.2 to 2023-06 + slf4j v2.0 + logback v1.3